# Layering mark_line onto an interactive line plot significantly decreases performance in Altair

Tags: python, pandas, altair

Here's a dummy data set I created to illustrate my problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt

# Use more rows than recommended so it's a bit easier to 
# see the slowdown with human eyes.
alt.data_transformers.disable_max_rows()

# Create N rows with 2 columns. 
N=10000
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'t' : range(0, N, 1), # Integers counting up from 0 to N - 1.
                        'A' : np.random.randint(0, 100, size=N)}) # random integer between 0 and 100.
```

I use it to create a line plot:

```
test_line = alt.Chart(test_df).mark_line().encode(x='t:Q', y='A:Q').interactive(bind_y=False)
```

All is good, even with more than 5000 rows, **the rendered interactive line chart is snappy when I pan-and-zoom**. This is obviously machine-dependent (ie, running this code on a different machine will result in different performance in the pan-and-zoom).

Moving forward, I tried to draw a vertical line to mark a point of interest. The code is inspired by [this](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1124#issuecomment-417714535).

```
v_rule = alt.Chart(test_df).mark_rule(color='red').encode(x='a:Q').transform_calculate(a=str(5000))
alt.layer(test_line, v_rule).display()
```

With this, the resulting interactive line chart is **slow to pan-and-zoom with the vertical line on-screen**:

[image]

If I move the plot around such that **the vertical line is not on-screen, the pan-and-zoom becomes snappy again**.

[image]

This problem becomes much worse when I try to concatenate multiple plots together, each of which is also interactive and has a vertical line.

Is there a better way to draw this vertical line? Some way to pre-render everything in advance and save to a local file? I am surprised (and confused) how a single line could be so detrimental to the rendering speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the vertical line but `tranform_calculate` that causes the performance penalty. The reason is that the value is being calculated for each row in your dataframe, you can see that if you click on the three dots action button, "Open chart in Vega Editor", click `Data Viewer` to the right and select `data_1`. I believe this is also the reason why the line looks a bit thicker in the plot, there might be 10000 lines on top of each other.

To create just a single line, you can do this instead:

```
v_rule = alt.Chart(pd.DataFrame({'a': [5000]})).mark_rule(color='red').encode(x='a')
alt.layer(test_line, v_rule)
```

Comment: Man...that fixed it. Words can't describe how thankful I am. In general, should I just be careful about using `transform_calculate`, especially on a large data set? Or is the problem here that _all_ the `transform_calculate` results are stacked on top of each other, so the renderer has to work extra hard to display 10000 lines on one screen?

Comment: @KenLin Happy it helped =) In general, too many plotted elements can slow down the interactive charts, particularly when you are zoomed out and have all of them in the same view. There is nothing in particular about `transform_calculate` you need to watch out for I believe.

Comment: One more question, I don't actually have "Open Chart in Vega Editor". Instead, I have "View Source" and "View Compiled Vega". Could I have used either of those two to help me debug that there were too many things being rendered on the screen? I really did not realize I have 10000 lines on the screen. I was sure it was just one big line.

Comment: @KenLin Normally there is one more item under "View Compiled Vega" so make sure that you can see the entire menu. You can see an example on the charts in the docs, e.g. here https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/scatter_tooltips.html

Comment: Hmm I was using an internal version at work. I'll try to set up one on my own personal machine to see if that works. Thanks!